# Git log command to display the output of a range of commits?

Tags: range, git-log

Is there a git log syntax for displaying the output of a list of commits, such as commits between ref1 and ref2, or 10 commits leading up to and after a ref, or made within a certain time of the ref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log SHA_HASHREF1..SHA_HASHREF2
```

has always worked for me for displaying between two specific commits

Hey look, documentation http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log :)

You can use the following parameters to figure out commits within the time of the ref

```
--since=<date>
--after=<date>
```